How to modify column labels with modelsummary
How can I modify the labelling scheme for the column labels (here: lhs: mpg and lhs: disp) with modelsummary?
According to the documentation, setting a global option like this options(modelsummary_model_labels = "roman") should change the labelling scheme but I do not see any effect.
library(fixest)
library(modelsummary)
options(modelsummary_model_labels = "roman")

mods <- feols(c(mpg, disp) ~ wt, data = mtcars)

modelsummary(mods)





lhs: mpg
lhs: disp




(Intercept)
37.285
-131.148



(1.878)
(35.717)


wt
-5.344
112.478



(0.559)
(10.635)


Num.Obs.
32
32


R2
0.753
0.789


R2 Adj.
0.745
0.781


AIC
164.0
352.5


BIC
167.0
355.5


RMSE
2.95
56.10


Std.Errors
IID
IID



Created on 2024-05-30 with reprex v2.1.0


Session info

sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24)
#>  os       macOS Sonoma 14.5
#>  system   aarch64, darwin20
#>  ui       X11
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8
#>  ctype    en_US.UTF-8
#>  tz       Europe/Berlin
#>  date     2024-05-30
#>  pandoc   3.1.11 @ /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/tools/aarch64/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package      * version    date (UTC) lib source
#>  backports      1.4.1      2021-12-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  bayestestR     0.13.2     2024-02-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  checkmate      2.3.1      2023-12-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  cli            3.6.2      2023-12-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  data.table     1.15.4     2024-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  datawizard     0.10.0     2024-03-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  digest         0.6.35     2024-03-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  dreamerr       1.4.0      2023-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  evaluate       0.23       2023-11-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  fansi          1.0.6      2023-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  fastmap        1.2.0      2024-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  fixest       * 0.12.0     2024-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  Formula        1.2-5      2023-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  fs             1.6.4      2024-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  generics       0.1.3      2022-07-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  glue           1.7.0      2024-01-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  htmltools      0.5.8.1    2024-04-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  insight        0.19.11    2024-05-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  knitr          1.46       2024-04-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  lattice        0.22-6     2024-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  lifecycle      1.0.4      2023-11-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  magrittr       2.0.3      2022-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  modelsummary * 2.0.0      2024-03-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  nlme           3.1-164    2023-11-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  numDeriv       2016.8-1.1 2019-06-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  parameters     0.21.7     2024-05-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  performance    0.11.0     2024-03-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  purrr          1.0.2      2023-08-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  R.cache        0.16.0     2022-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  R.methodsS3    1.8.2      2022-06-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  R.oo           1.26.0     2024-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  R.utils        2.12.3     2023-11-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  Rcpp           1.0.12     2024-01-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  reprex         2.1.0      2024-01-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  rlang          1.1.3      2024-01-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  rmarkdown      2.27       2024-05-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  rstudioapi     0.16.0     2024-03-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  sandwich       3.1-0      2023-12-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  sessioninfo    1.2.2      2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  stringmagic    1.1.2      2024-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  styler         1.10.3     2024-04-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  tables         0.9.25     2024-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  tinytable      0.2.1      2024-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  vctrs          0.6.5      2023-12-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  withr          3.0.0      2024-01-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  xfun           0.44       2024-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  yaml           2.3.8      2023-12-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  zoo            1.8-12     2023-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#> 
#>  [1] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/library
#> 
#> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────


This global option only affects situations when mods is an unnamed list. Your fixest command is a special case that returns a named list. You can remove the names manually to get roman numerals:
library(fixest)
library(modelsummary)
options(modelsummary_model_labels = "roman")
mods <- feols(c(mpg, disp) ~ wt, data = mtcars)
mods <- as.list(mods)
names(mods) <- NULL
modelsummary(mods)


To explain further, the modelsummary function has a check right at the top if (is.null(names(models))). This means that if the models object has names, it will skip the whole process of renaming the models into roman or arabic etc but instead will simply use the model names.

Thanks a lot! In this case I wish there was an option to overwrite existing names on the side of modelsummary() itself because the list of models I am passing to it might contain a mix of fixest_multi and regular fixest objects that I would have to convert to lists and unname individually, and finally flatten into a single list with the other objects.
